# Singular fit with simplest random structure in lmer (lme4), is a Bayesian approach the only option?

Tags: r, bayesian, lme4-nlme, singular-matrix

I'm running a mixed model with the `lmer` function from the lme4 package in R and ran into some issues with singular fits. I get the warning message *'singular fit'*, which is specified as *'convergence code 0; 1 optimizer warnings; 0 lme4 warnings'* in  `summary(model)`.

Just as background information, I recently re-installed my computer (MacOS) and I can't remember that I had the same issue  before. Thus, something might have changed, which could explain that the issue emerged (see also [this thread here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392302/singular-fit-in-lmer-despite-no-high-correlations-of-random-effects), where somebody only got the message after some unknown changes, possibly updates).

Based on [this thread here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378939/dealing-with-singular-fit-in-mixed-models), I first thought that the random effect structure might be too complex for my dataset and simplified the model. However, I still got the same warning after building a model only including the random intercept for subject and nothing else: `lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|Subject))`

Therefore, I tried to reconstruct my dataset by only using the means and standard deviations from all subjects, and then simulate new data based on these values. My idea was to test whether the issue arises in similar datasets, and I also wanted to have a dataset that is easier to share here.

Running the same model as above on some of these new (partly random) datasets, I still have the same issue with the singular fit. However, I don't get it all the time (see below).

Therefore, I wanted to ask if anybody could give me a good explanation for this phenomenon.

Reproducible Example:

First, I defined a function to get n normally distributed, random values per subject, based on the mean and sd provided for each subject.

```
get_subject_df <- function(means, sds, samples_per_ind){
  ind_vars = vector(length = length(means) * samples_per_ind)  
  for(i in 1:length(means)){
    vals <- rnorm(n = samples_per_ind, mean = means[[i]], sd = sds[[i]])
    irows <-  ((i - 1) * samples_per_ind + 1):(i*samples_per_ind)
    ind_vars[irows] <- vals
    names(ind_vars)[irows] <- paste0("ID_", i)
  }
  df = data.frame(ID = names(ind_vars), vals = ind_vars)
  return(df)
}
```

Here, I create lists with means and sds for all subjects based on real data

```
subject_means <- c(9.70,  9.89,  9.72, 10.66,  9.83, 10.32, 10.35, 10.93, 14.36, 12.38, 
                   10.91, 10.38,  8.71, 10.21, 12.28, 11.42, 11.90, 11.41,  9.69,  
                   9.10, 10.20, 10.49, 10.11,  9.16, 10.74)
subject_sds   <- c(3.28, 3.12, 4.91, 4.49, 3.08, 3.67, 4.08, 3.99, 6.10, 5.32, 3.04, 
                   4.69, 3.54, 4.63, 5.47, 3.46, 6.05, 5.94, 3.27, 4.18, 3.41, 4.21, 
                   4.59, 3.28, 4.15)
```

I ran the  model `y ~ 1 + (1|Subject)` several times using different values for `set.seed()` and singular fit issues arises with some but not all models. (E.g. when the value for `set.seed()` is 2, 4, 8, there is an issue but not with 1, 3, 5, ....). Here's a model with the issue (note that the sd for the random intercept for ID is 0.)

```
set.seed(2)
df_1 <- get_subject_df(means=subject_means, sds=subject_sds, samples_per_ind=5)
lme4::lmer(vals ~ 1 + (1|ID), data = df_1)

singular fit 
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod'] 
Formula: vals ~ 1 + (1 | ID)   
Data: df_1 

REML criterion at convergence: 751.7272 

Random effects:
  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
  ID       (Intercept) 0.000
  Residual             4.917   
 Number of obs: 125, groups:  ID, 25 

Fixed Effects: 
 (Intercept)  
      10.64 

convergence code 0; 1 optimizer warnings; 0 lme4 warnings
```

Models where values for all subjects have the same standard deviation (here 2) don't seem to have that problem (I tried all values between 1 and 1000 in  `set.seed()`, and never had an issue with singular fit).

```
set.seed(1)
df_2 <- get_subject_df(means=subject_means, sds=rep(2, length(subject_means)),
                         samples_per_ind=5)
lme4::lmer(vals ~ 1 + (1|ID), data=df_2)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: vals ~ 1 + (1 | ID)
   Data: df_2
REML criterion at convergence: 524.5715
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 1.134   
 Residual             1.766   
Number of obs: 125, groups:  ID, 25
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  
      10.81
```

---

Edit:
I went through the links provided by Ben Bolker in the comments and also through the other sources that were linked within these threads. If I understand it correctly, there are the following (potential) options to deal with such singular models (as summarized [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1)):

1. Simplify the random structure. Not possible in my case as I already used the simplest random effect structure that is possible and an intercept-only model.
2. Fit the random effect as fixed effect. However, it seems that this suggestion applies to scenarios where the number of random-effect levels is very low (<5), which is not the case here (25 levels).
3. Use a Bayesian approach.

**Thus, my open questions is whether my only option is to use a Bayesian approach?**

Comment: have you read https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115090/why-do-i-get-zero-variance-of-a-random-effect-in-my-mixed-model-despite-some-va ; https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/random-effect-equal-to-0-in-generalized-linear-mixed-model/34979#34979 yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get zero variance of a random effect in my mixed model, despite some variation in the data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115090/why-do-i-get-zero-variance-of-a-random-effect-in-my-mixed-model-despite-some-va)

Comment: I edited my question above. As far as I can tell, the other threads explain the phenomenon but none of the answers (at least not those provided on stackexchange) help me to deal with the problem.

Comment: You already excluded option 1) and 2) for yourself. I would say you have (at least) two further options: go Bayesian (`rstanarm::stan_lmer()` gives you the same estimate for the intercept, and ~.85 for the SD of the group factor/random effect). Second option, also in Ben Bolkers FAQ: "Conversely, if one chooses for philosophical grounds to retain these parameters, it won’t change any of the answers." - so, if you think there's a good reason, you can live with the singularity.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your answer. Over the last year, I have started to use rstanarm, brms, rethinking, and other R packages to conduct bayesian data analysis in R. It's a lot of fun. Urs